# Intercept Property Binding

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Following situation:

```
DoubleProperty p1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
DoubleProperty p2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(5.5);

p1.bind(p2);
```

Is it somehow possible to modify this straight-forward way to intercept the value setting process in order to modify the set value?

Comment: Modify it how? There are various ways to create custom bindings, if you need, but I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If `SimpleDoubleProperty` is not final you can override the `bind()` function as follows and create an anonymous subclass:

```
DoubleProperty p1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0){
    @Override
    public void bind(DoubleProperty property){
        // do your interception-magic here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to perform simple arithmetic on the value, you can use the bindings API, which supports a pretty rich set of arithmetic functions:

```
p1.bind(p2.multiply(p2).add(1));
```

will make sure that `p1` is always equal to `p2*p2+1` (just as an arbitrary example), and

```
p1.bind(Bindings
    .when(p2.lessThan(0))
    .then(0)
    .otherwise(p2));
```

will ensure that `p1` is always equal to `p2` when `p2` is non-negative, and `p1` is zero otherwise.

If that doesn't suffice for your needs, you can use a custom binding, for example:

```
p1.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    double p2Value = p2.getValue();
    double interceptedValue = ... ;
    return interceptedValue ;
}, p2);
```

The last argument is a varargs of `Observable`, so you can list any properties (or other observables) there that you want to trigger an invalidation of the binding.

An equivalent way is to subclass `DoubleBinding`:

```
p1.bind(new DoubleBinding() {
    {
        bind(p2); // and to other properties if needed...
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeValue() {
        double p2Value = p2.getValue();
        double interceptedValue = ... ;
        return interceptedValue ;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess that would do what I need. But: I tried to do this in the `@FXML public void initialize() {..}` method of the controller and I get a "Bound values cannot be set" Exception - probably by the layouting engine itself.

Comment: @Hannes That sounds independent of this. You can't set bound values, whether you bind them directly to another property or to a more complex binding. What are you trying to bind?

Comment: The layoutXProperty of a TextField to the respective property of a ComboBox

Comment: @Hannes The layout mechanism of a pane will set the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties of its child nodes, in order to position them according to the pane's layout strategy. It's basically always a mistake to use bindings to force the layout you want. Use a [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) that positions them relative to each other in the way you want. If there's really no layout pane that does what you want (which is hard to believe), then subclass `Pane` and override the `layoutChildren` (and other) methods to layout the nodes

Comment: What I want to archive: I have three Fields in a row and in certain situations the second one is invisible and the third should take the second's position and the fourth the third's. I figured binding the X and than only recalculate the X of the third would make it easier to move them.

Comment: @Hannes "Invisible" as in `setVisible(false)`? And they are in a `HBox`?

Comment: setInvisible, no HBox

Comment: So what layout are you using? This is really a layout question, it has nothing to do with bindings. You should probably post an actual question about the problem you are trying to solve.